# Is it possible to make dua to Allah to see Allah in my dream for guidance?

Tags: allah, dua, dream

I want to see Allah in my dream asking if I am going towards Jannah.

Comment: This post could use some more information details. And if you got an answer what will that change? And who knows if it is a good dream from Allah or a bad...

Answer (score 1):

Assalamoalikum.

No one can see Allah **before death**. The only person that is known to witness Allah is Prophet Mohammad (PBUH). Musa (AS) asked Allah to show him on a mountain and only in a moment he fainted and the mountain crashed down at the appearance of Allah. Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) witnessed and communicated with Allah (SWT) on the night of Mairaj.

**“It is not fitting for a man that Allah should speak to him except by inspiration or from behind a veil or by the sending of a Messenger to reveal with Allah's permission what Allah wills, for He is Most High Most Wise” (Qur'an, Al-Shura, 51)**

This Ayah makes it clear that it is not fitting for a normal man to see Allah (SWT).

Comment: Just a simple correction to your answer. Prophet Musa didn't see Allah. What happened is that Allah appeared to the Mountain and the mountain was destroyed and prophet Musa fainted. The original Ayah: "وَلَمَّا جَاءَ مُوسَىٰ لِمِيقَاتِنَا وَكَلَّمَهُ رَبُّهُ قَالَ رَبِّ أَرِنِي أَنظُرْ إِلَيْكَ ۚ قَالَ لَن تَرَانِي وَلَٰكِنِ انظُرْ إِلَى الْجَبَلِ فَإِنِ اسْتَقَرَّ مَكَانَهُ فَسَوْفَ تَرَانِي ۚ فَلَمَّا تَجَلَّىٰ رَبُّهُ لِلْجَبَلِ جَعَلَهُ دَكًّا وَخَرَّ مُوسَىٰ صَعِقًا ۚ فَلَمَّا أَفَاقَ قَالَ سُبْحَانَكَ تُبْتُ إِلَيْكَ وَأَنَا أَوَّلُ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ" Al-A'raaf 143 Sorry for my bad English

Comment: @MohamedMedhat Thanks for correcting brother, “And when Moses came to Our appointed tryst and his Lord spoke with him, he said: ‘My Lord, show me (Yourself), that I may look towards You!’ He (Allah) said: ‘Never shall you see Me, but look towards the mountain: if it remains firm in its place, then you will see Me.’ So when his Lord manifested (His) glory to the mountain, He sent it crashing down, and Moses fell down senseless. Then when he recovered, he said: ‘Glory be to You! I turn to You (repentant), and I am the first of the believers’.”

But that's the reason he fainted, right?

Comment: @MohamedMedhat Why would he faint If he weren't looking at the mountain where Allah revealed himself for a moment, which crashed the mountain.

Comment: @MohamedMedhat I think what I answered is correct, other Fatwas also say that because of seeing he fainted, and of course, the mountain shattered. Oh and also, Stranger is my phone account, I answered when I was on phone.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan We shouldn't make conclusions if the text is explicit.  "قَالَ لَن تَرَانِي" means "you won't see me" then "وَلَٰكِنِ انظُرْ إِلَى الْجَبَلِ فَإِنِ اسْتَقَرَّ مَكَانَهُ فَسَوْفَ تَرَانِي" means "But look at the mountain, if it stayed stable, you will see me". then "فَلَمَّا تَجَلَّىٰ رَبُّهُ لِلْجَبَلِ جَعَلَهُ دَكًّا وَخَرَّ مُوسَىٰ صَعِقًا" means "when Allah appeared to the mountain it is destroyed, and Musa fainted". Btw, I'm a native Arabic speaker and all the sheikhs I know never said that Musa saw Allah.

Comment: @MohamedMedhat Agreed brother, may Allah bless you for correcting me. Allow me to edit my post.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Thanks brother. Btw, some friend told me something about islam.stackexchange. He told me that religious issues shouldn't be discussed using up-votes. He told me: "Think what might go wrong". He is right btw. He also passed me this website where you can search for questions and ask Sheikhs with religious science about whatever you want :). https://www.islamweb.net/en/

Comment: @MohamedMedhat That's great but the thing in this site is that anyone can answer questions without proof of their qualification(s). That's the reason I prefer islamqa.com for more Fiqh (Islamic Jurisprudence) related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

`Is it possible to make dua to Allah to see Allah in my dream for guidance?`

If it were possible to make a dua to Allah asking to see Him then He would have informed us about such dua in His book Quran. But unforetunately in Quran there is no such dua.

As for the `guidance`, Quran, book of Allah, is the perfect guidance. Whatever a believer (Mumin) needs to be guided is given in It. So believer should read, learn Quran and act upon It in order to be guided.

> [image]
>
> **This is the Book (the Quran)**, whereof there is no doubt, **a guidance** to
> those who are Al-Muttaqun.
>
> <sup>[Sura Baqara (2), verse 2, Muhsin Khan's translation](https://legacy.quran.com/2/2)</sup>

> [image]
>
> **This (Quran) is a guidance**. And those who disbelieve in the Ayat
> (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) of
> their Lord, for them there is a painful torment of Rijz (a severe kind
> of punishment).
>
> <sup>[Sura Al-Jāthiyah (45), verse 11, Muhsin Khan's
> translation](https://legacy.quran.com/45/11)</sup>

`I want to see Allah in my dream asking if I am going towards Jannah.`

The condition to enter Jannah is **Belief** and **Righteous deeds**.

> [image]
>
> And those who believe and do righteous good deeds, they are dwellers
> of Paradise, they will dwell therein forever.
>
> <sup>[Sura Baqara (2), verse 82, Muhsin Khan's translation](https://legacy.quran.com/2/82)</sup>

So one should believe and do as much righteous good deeds as possible to enter Jannah.

Comment: I think his main question was If he can see Allah in his dreams, but yes your answer is also valid. Also, "Quran, book of Allah, is the perfect guidance" one tiny correction for this phrase, "Qur'an, book of Allah, and sunnah, footsteps of the Prophet (PBUH) are the perfect guidance."

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan My question can i make dua for allah being my dream to communicate if I am in right path to go Jannah.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed See my answer, Allah does not communicate directly with normal people. The only ways Allah communicates directly with people that aren't Prophets is by a Prophet, or by inspiration, and inspiration only when the person is related to a Prophet or a Wali (close servant of Allah).

Normal people cannot directly in any way communicate with Allah. However, THE ONES THAT WANT TO BE GUIDED TO THE RIGHT PATH! Allah never leaves them unguided. If you want to be on the right path Allah will get you to it, trust Allah as the highest sign of a believer is infinite trust in Allah.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed Also, you asked about the ability to "SEE" Allah in a dream, which is also not possible for anyone other than a Prophet and even in all the known Prophets only two of them, Musa (AS) and Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) saw Allah, and only Mohammad (PBUH) was able to communicate with Allah WHILE WITNESSING HIM.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed Also, Stranger is my phone account.